# Using scope in Rails model for gathering "private" posts

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, scope, erb, rails-activerecord

I have a table of user Posts, some of which are private, denoted by a boolean column (privacy) in the table (true being private). In my livefeed view (posts/index.html.erb), I want to show only the non-private posts for ALL users. Can I do this via my scope?

Note: In my usersfeed view I am showing private and non-private posts for the current_user.

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # the top scope is sorting by "featured" posts (a boolean column in the Posts table)
  scope :livefeed_order, order('featured DESC, created_at DESC').limit(40)
  scope :userfeed_order, order('created_at DESC')
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, except: [:show]

  def index #Livefeed
    @posts = Post.livefeed_order
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.userfeed_order
  end
end
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create another scope called say 'public',

```
#in your model
scope :public, lambda { 
  :conditions => { privacy: false }
}

#in your index action
@posts = Post.livefeed_order.public
```

Idea is , you can chain scopes,

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Rails >=4.1 no longer allows scopes with names that match BLACKLISTED_CLASS_METHODS (I.E. `public`, `private`, `protected`, `allocate`, `new`, `name`, `parent`, `superclass` ...see: [BLACKLISTED_CLASS_METHODS](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08576b94ad4f19dfc368619d7751e211d23dcad8/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L35) and [dangerous_class_method?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08576b94ad4f19dfc368619d7751e211d23dcad8/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L35) on GitHub). So, ...

...while this:

```
scope :public, -> { where(privacy: false) }
```

...is fine for Rails <4.1, you might want to try something like

```
scope :only_public, -> { where(privacy: false) }
scope :only_private, -> { where(privacy: true) }
```

...to ensure future compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, particularly for the suggestion of what name to use now that I can't use just `public` or `private`.